# Postfix rejecting outgoing emails because of "Relay access denied." | "generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2"

Tags: debian, email, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I am currently rolling out a Postfix/Dovecot configuration on our servers to replace our monolithic mail server.

On the test enviroment I have everything set up and it worked there. Now I am rolling out the configuration on 5 more servers, unfortunately nothing works as desired here.

When I try to send an email from a legitimate mail address to external (e.g. gmail), I get the following error message:

> Relay access denied
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: match_list_match: REMOVED: no match
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=0
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: reject_unauth_destination: REMOVED@gmail.com
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: permit_auth_destination: REMOVED@gmail.com
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key test@REMOVED.com?REMOVED@gmail.com
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from REMOVED[REMOVED]: 554 5.7.1 REMOVED@gmail.com: Relay access denied; from=test@REMOVED.com to=REMOVED@gmail.com proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.10.39]>
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
> Sep 14 10:23:51 px-10042 postfix/smtpd[21569]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<

If I send a mail to an internal address or to my own, from which I also send, it works without problems.

The mail server should forward all mails it receives to one of our three proxmox mail gateways. Likewise, incoming emails are also only accepted by the Proxmox mail gateway. This is configured in the DNS settings and works fine in our monolith as well as in the first test environment.

Here are the outputs from postconf -n:

```
    append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1h
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, ::1, REMOVED
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 15m
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1h
message_size_limit = 52428800
minimal_backoff_time = 5m
mua_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mua_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
mydomain = REMOVED
myhostname = REMOVED
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
queue_run_delay = 5m
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [REMOVED.de]:26
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/without_ptr reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/px_network.crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/px_network.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
tls_medium_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
tls_preempt_cipherlist = no
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/accounts.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

And thats the master.cf:

```
###
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
###
###
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd 
###
###
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
###
###
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
###
###
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd 
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
    -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=$mua_relay_restrictions
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
    -o smtpd_helo_required=no
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup

smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=$mua_relay_restrictions
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
  -o smtpd_helo_required=no
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o cleanup_service_name=submission-header-cleanup


###
###
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
###
###
submission-header-cleanup unix n - n    -       0       cleanup
    -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_cleanup
```

And thats the output for postconf -P:

```
smtp/inet/smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
submission/inet/cleanup_service_name = submission-header-cleanup
submission/inet/milter_macro_daemon_name = ORIGINATING
submission/inet/smtpd_client_restrictions = $mua_client_restrictions
submission/inet/smtpd_helo_required = no
submission/inet/smtpd_helo_restrictions =
submission/inet/smtpd_relay_restrictions = $mua_relay_restrictions
submission/inet/smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
submission/inet/smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
submission/inet/smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
submission/inet/smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
submission/inet/smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
submission/inet/smtpd_sender_restrictions = $mua_sender_restrictions
submission/inet/smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
submission/inet/syslog_name = postfix/submission
smtps/inet/cleanup_service_name = submission-header-cleanup
smtps/inet/milter_macro_daemon_name = ORIGINATING
smtps/inet/smtpd_client_restrictions = $mua_client_restrictions
smtps/inet/smtpd_helo_required = no
smtps/inet/smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtps/inet/smtpd_relay_restrictions = $mua_relay_restrictions
smtps/inet/smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtps/inet/smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtps/inet/smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtps/inet/smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtps/inet/smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/sender-login-maps.cf
smtps/inet/smtpd_sender_restrictions = $mua_sender_restrictions
smtps/inet/smtpd_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtps/inet/syslog_name = postfix/smtps
submission-header-cleanup/unix/header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_cleanup
```

Thank you in advance.